# Deploy playframework without java logging instance

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi guys so I have written my play application and all is working fine.

I am installing this on a windows machine, and I need it to be up 24/7. I want it all to be automatic so the user does not have to go into command and run play start everytime the computer restarts or there is an issue.

So I wrote a c# wrapper service that monitors the RUNNING_PID to check if the service is running, if not opens a new cmd prompt and runs play start.

So this is working atm, but when you run play start it opens up two java processes 1 being the actual service and the other is a logging service.
[image: Image of the two java processes]

Is there a way to not have this open? either a configuration option or extra launch parameter?

Any other ideas on how I could get around this?

Ive had a look at using stage and dist but I've found they dont work. once the file is created the new start command doesnt do anything.

Comment: `dist` is proper way to do that task. I think you should pay more attention to check why the generated `start` script doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I remember the start script created is for *nix system only, no?

Comment: I think you are right Michael, any ideas on how to do it in windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys so I found a solution.

Using dist now and then creating a new start.bat file with the below script:

```
@echo off

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
  set "DIRNAME=%~dp0%"
) else (
  set DIRNAME=.\
)
java -cp "%DIRNAME%\lib\*" %* play.core.server.NettyServer
```

I solution was solved here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/108788785914419775677/posts/RxohCRp52J5

I'm still not sure how to automatically include this new script file into the dist zip file. If anyone knows how to do this would be helpful?